# hamburger menu disconnected with navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have the navbar go directly below the hamburger menu button in mobile view when i open the menu. But right now its going below the image instead and has a disconnected look.

How would I be able to make it go below the hamburger button?

Toggle navigation

```
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xbemtom0/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just add as below that work's, there was placement issue for image div.

```
<div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul> </div>

<div class="row picture" >
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com"/>
</div>

</div>
</nav>
```

(Or)

```
<nav class="nav navbar-default">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-right">
<li>Search</li>
<li>Language</li>
<li>Account</li>
<li>Bag</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="container header">
<div class="row top-right-nav">

</div>

<div class="row picture" >
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com"/>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-hamburger"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#collapsemenu"
>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul> </div>
</nav></div>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">


<h2>hi</h2>
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- content container -->

.top-right{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: The issue is when it's not mobile the navigation row is above the image..I how can i keep the image above the header. how do we solve this?

Comment: Try the or one, we have assigned to nav, one at top-right and another responsive.